Techniques for bounding the operator norm of the expectation of random matrix?
Let $\mu$ be a distribution on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $u \sim \mu$ and consider the random matrix
$$
A = I_n - uu^T.
$$
Question: What techniques are available to provide (reasonably good) estimates of
$$
\mathscr{M}(\mu) = \| \mathbb{E}[A] \| = \sup_{\|t\|_2 = 1} \mathbb{E} [1 - \langle t, u\rangle^2]?
$$
Clearly $0 \leq \mathscr{M}(\mu) \leq 1$. However, I am wondering are there better bounds that can be had? For instance, perhaps we can relate $\mathscr{M}(\mu)$ to higher moments of $u \sim \mu$? My primary interest is when the dimension $n$ is large.

As you are asking for techniques, you surely have already thought to begin by Dirac distributions : in this case, $A$ is just a projection on the hyperplane $u^{\perp}$, then proceed to linear combinations of Diracs, then proceed to continuous distributions...

Is it more clear what to do for discrete distributions? What you propose would amount to considering $\mu = \sum_{m = 1}^N p_m \delta_{u_m}$, where $\sum_m p_m = 1, p_m > 0$, and $u_m \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. However, we need to consider $N \geq n$ otherwise $\mathscr{M}(\mu) = 1$. My primary interest is in behavior in high dimensions ($n$ is large) so this requires that $N$ is large too.

The fact that for a Dirac dist., your operator is an orthogonal projection on a (n-1)-dimensional space should be useful, at one moment or another...

For a point mass $\mu = \delta_u$, what you're saying is true. But my operator for the mixture $\mu$ ("linear combination of diracs") is $I - \sum_{m = 1}^N p_m u_m u_m^T$. But this already seems to exhibit a range of behaviors. For instance say $N = n$ and $p_m = 1/n$; if ${u_m}{m \leq n}$ is an orthonormal basis, $M(\mu) = 1 - 1/n$. On the other hand, if $u_m = u{m'}$ then $M(\mu) = 1$.

When $\mu$ is concentrated at a single point $u_0$ on the sphere, we have $\mathbb{E}[uu^T] = u_0u_0^T$ and $\mathscr{M}(\mu) = \|I_n - u_0u_0^T\| = 1$, achieving the upper bound of $\mathscr{M}(\mu)$.
For a completely uniform distribution over the sphere, we have $\mathbb{E}[uu^T] = \frac{1}{n}I_n$. This result relies on the isotropic nature of the uniform distribution on the sphere. It can be derived from the fact that the trace of $\mathbb{E}[uu^T]$ must equal 1 (since each $u$ is a unit vector) and by symmetry, each diagonal entry of $\mathbb{E}[uu^T]$ is the same and all off-diagonal entries are zero. In this case, $\mathscr{M}(\mu) = \|I_n - \frac{1}{n}I_n\| = \|(1 - \frac{1}{n})I_n\| = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$.
For a discrete mixture distribution $\mu = \sum_{m=1}^N p_m\delta(u_m)$, where $\sum_m p_m = 1$, $p_m > 0$, and $u_m \in S^{n-1}$, we have:
$$\mathbb{E}[uu^T] = \sum_{m=1}^N p_mu_mu_m^T$$
The computation of $\mathscr{M}(\mu)$ in this case depends on how the vectors $u_m$ are positioned on the sphere and their corresponding probabilities $p_m$.
$\mathscr{M}(\mu)$ serves as a measure of non-uniformity, quantifying the maximum deviation of $\mu$ from the uniform distribution in any direction. Values close to 1 indicate high concentration, while values close to 0 indicate a more uniform spread. For any fixed distribution type that is not perfectly uniform, $\mathscr{M}(\mu)$ tends to increase with $n$, approaching 1 as $n$ approaches infinity: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathscr{M}(\mu) = 1$.  Even small deviations from uniformity in any one dimension can lead to large overall deviations in high-dimensional space. Conversely, for the uniform distribution, $\mathscr{M}(\mu) = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ approaches 0 as $n$ increases, reflecting less deviation from uniformity in higher dimensions.
Also $\mathscr{M}(\mu)$ is invariant under rotations of the sphere. For any orthogonal matrix $Q$, we have $\mathscr{M}(Q\mu) = \mathscr{M}(\mu)$, where $Q\mu$ denotes the pushed-forward measure.
